# HTML error when including a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This should not at all be difficult but I can't get a simple JavaScript file included in a flat HTML page.

My JavaScript file is as follows:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').css('background', 'red');
 });
</script>
```

HTML code is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    </head>
    <title>Song Index!</title>
    <body>
        <div>It's working!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have confirmed both javascript files are in my **js** folder.

However, on Chrome I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < init.js:1
```

Firefox renders a slightly different error:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error   <script> init.js (line 1)
```

I just don't get why it's not working.

Comment: Remove `<script></script>` tags from the javascript file

Comment: SLEEP DEPRAVATION - makes a developer do some dumb things :-)  Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have script in a separate file the `<script></script>` is not required.

Your script is included within the `html` page using a `script` tag, so within your script file `js/init.js` there should not be the `<script>` and `</script>` parts

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('div').css('background', 'red');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript file should not containc  tag.
You javascript should be:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('div').css('background', 'red');
   });
```

Please move your  tag in side  tag.
HTML code should be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <title>Song Index!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>It's working!</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `<script>` tags from the external JS file:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div').css('background', 'red');
    });
```